# How to get facebook friend's email list using facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

We are going to use facebook graph API to import user friend's from facebook to our site(Website)

I have used following code to imports facebook friend's

```
FB.api(
  '/me',
  'GET',
  {"fields":"friends{email,name,work,education,birthday}"},
  function(response) {

  }
);
```

When we hit this API we got following Json response

```
{
  "friends": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "XXXXXXXX",
        "education": [
          {
            "school": {
              "id": "XXXXXXXXXX",
              "name": "XXXXXX"
            },
            "type": "XXXXXXX"
          },
          {
            "school": {
              "id": "XXXXXXXXX",
              "name": "XXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "type": "XXXXXXXXX",
            "with": [
              {
                "id": "XXXXXXX",
                "name": "XXXXX"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "school": {
              "id": "XXXXXXX",
              "name": "XXXXXX"
            },
            "type": "XXXXXX"
          }
        ],
        "birthday": "XXXX",
        "id": "XXXXXX"
      }
    ]
  },
  "id": "XXXXXXXXX"
}
```

But we not getting the friend's emails in user friend's list

Can facebook provide email of user friend's??
if yes please share the documents

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can only get email addresses from people that granted your app user_email

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't receive the email addresses of a user's friends via the Graph API. I guess this is to avoid spam.

Comment: Is their any python Django API of facebook to import friends list with emails